# What does the Windows folder Tasks_Migrated do?

Tags: windows-10

What does it do? I haven't found any documentation anywhere by DuckDuckGoing, Binging or Googleing

Comment: Where are you seeing this? Screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: I think it is due to an upgrade of the OS, it stores tasks of the previous OS in there then migrates them back into task scheduler during install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26b0ec23-f293-4786-a503-8206fa821c4b/task-scheduler-wont-merge-old-and-new-default-tasks-after-win10-upgrade?forum=win10itprogeneral) says those are Scheduled Tasks which were in your prior Windows OS version which didn't migrate properly when you upgraded.